# Converting String Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a String i.e.

**`"DateAdd('y', 1, [CreatedOnDate])"`**

And I want to replace y as year and DateAdd as DATEADD

**`"DATEADD('year', 1, [CreatedOnDate])"`**

I want the solution for this.

I have tried

```
let formulaNameIndex = formula.formula.indexOf('(');
let formulaName = formula.formula.substring(0, formulaNameIndex);
let yearIndex = formulaNameIndex + 1;
let yearName = formula.formula.substring(yearIndex, yearIndex+1);
if (yearName === 'y') {
  yearName = 'year';
}

switch (formulaName) {
    case 'DateAdd':
      let newFormula = 'DATEADD(' + yearName ...
      break;
}
```

I got this as a temporary solution but I got 50 more String Manipulation So I can not do this for all 50 different String.
So I need a solution how to do this better than this.

Comment: _“that's why my question was I want an optimized solution for this”_ - we can not give you a solution, since you did not manage to present the _problem_ in a comprehensive way yet. You told us what you want to replace with what for _one single example_ so far - so what are the other replacements you need to perform for the other 50 strings? Do they all follow a specific pattern? Maybe you can put the name of the field, and what you want to replace inside of it, in some sort of array structure that you can then _loop_ over, something like that …

Comment: There is no pattern, Here are some of the strings 
DateAdd  DATEADD
DateDiff  DATEDIFF
DateSerial  DATEFROMPARTS
DateValue  CONVERT
Day  DAY
Exp  EXP
Hour  DATEPART
IIF  
InStr  CHARINDEX
InStrRev  CHARINDEX

Comment: storing in an array is nice Idea @misorude

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make cases for all possibilities, you can just use upperCase function

```
    let formula = "DateAdd('y', 1, [CreatedOnDate])";
    let formulaNameIndex = formula.indexOf('(');
    let formulaName = formula.substring(0, formulaNameIndex);
    let dateAdd = formula.substring(0, 7);
    let yearIndex = formulaNameIndex + 2;
    let yearName = formula.substring(yearIndex, yearIndex+1);
    if (yearName == 'y' || yearName == 'Y') {
    yearName = 'year';
    }

    finalFormula = dateAdd.toUpperCase() + "('" +  yearName + "', [CreatedOnDate])"
    alert (finalFormula);
```